# Load file dynamically from jar

Tags: java, json, netbeans, jar

I am trying to read a .json file I am packaging with my .jar.

The problem - finding the file so that I can parse it in.

The strange bit is that this code works in NetBeans, likely due to the way these methods work and the way NetBeans handles the dev workspace. When I build the jar and run it, however, it throws an ugly error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`.

My code for getting the file is as such:

```
    //get json file
    File jsonFile = new File(AndensMountain.class.getResource("/Anden.json").toURI());
    FileReader jsonFileReader;
    jsonFileReader = new FileReader(jsonFile);

    //load json file
    String json = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(jsonFileReader);
    while (br.ready()) {
        json += br.readLine() + "\n";
    }
```

I have gotten it to work if I allow it to read from the same directory as the jar, but this is not what I want - the .json is in the jar and I want to read it from in the jar.

I've looked around and as far as I can see this should work but it isn't.

If you are interested, this is the code before trying to get it to read out of the jar (which works as long as Anden.json is in the same directory as AndensMountain.jar):

```
    //get json file
    String path = AndensMountain.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
    File jsonFileBuilt = new File(new File(path).getParentFile(), "Anden.json");
    File jsonFileDev = new File(new File(path), "Anden.json");
    FileReader jsonFileReader;
    try {
        jsonFileReader = new FileReader(jsonFileBuilt);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        jsonFileReader = new FileReader(jsonFileDev);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(AndensMountain.class.getResourceAsStream("/Anden.json"), "UTF-8");
```

`AndensMountain.class.getResource("/Anden.json")` URL when ran outside a jar (for example, when the classes are compiled to a "classes/" directory) is a "file://" URL.

That is not the case when ran from inside a jar: it then becomes a "jar://" URL.

The `java.io.File` doesn't know how to handle this type of URL. It handles only "file://".

Anyway you don't really need to treat it as a File. You can manipulate the URL itself (either to navigate to a parent directory, for example) or to get its contents (via `openStream()`, or if you need to add headers, via `openConnection()`).

`java.lang.Class#getResourceAsStream()` as I suggested is just shorthand to `Class#getResource()` followed by `openStream()` on its result.

Comment: This is what I needed. Java IO (any IO really) will be the end of me I can tell XD